# Use lapply for a recursion (so without a foor loop)

Tags: r, recursion, lapply

I'd like to solve a recursion function in R, which is defined as

```
p(t) = 0.5p(t-1) + 0.2p(t-2)
```

for t = 3,...,100, where the initial values `p(1), p(2)` are given.

I know that this would be possible to solve using a for loop just like this one here: [Using R to solve a recursion function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688697/using-r-to-solve-a-recursion-function)

I'm wondering whether this is also possible using  the `lapply()` function in R? I think it should somehow be possible, but I don't know where to start. I'd appreciate any hint.

Comment: `lapply` works similar to for-loop construct. It iterates a list object, processes it and returns it as a list only.

Comment: Look into help("Reduce").

Comment: I m not sure I got it right but you can use `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE` argument. Something along the lines of `Reduce(function(x, y) y = 0.5*x+0.2*x, 3:100, accumulate = TRUE)`

Comment: @Sotos thanks for your comment. sorry, but there's a mistake in the question. it has to be p[t] = 0.5*p[t-1] + 0.2*p[t-2]

Comment: You should edit your question then and correct your mistake. Also an example along with expected output will be good too.

Comment: is `p` a function or  a vector?

Comment: it's a vector where the first two values are given and the subsequent values are determined by the recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use recursive function with lapply.

```
p <- function(t){
  if(t == 1){ return(1) } # arbitrary number
  if(t == 2){ return(2) } # arbitrary number

  return( 0.5*p(t-1) + 0.2*p(t-2) ) 
}

lapply(3:100, p)
```

Note that it is a bad idea to use a recursive function for this problem without some sort of memoization, because it will be of exponential complexity.

The following code works in linear time instead:

```
p_tab <- c(1, 2, rep(-1, 98)) # 1 and 2 arbitrary numbers
p <- function(t){
  if(p_tab[t] != -1) return(p_tab[t])

  p_tab[t] <<- 0.5*p_tab[t-1] + 0.2*p_tab[t-2]
}

p_tab <- unlist(lapply( 1:100, p))
```

`p_tab` will be filled with the numbers you need. `p_tab[100]` will be `p(100)` for instance, if that's the one you need.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please consider accepting as answer. :)